# how to fix an invalid character error in a csv file date conversion function

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I've been trying to convert a csv file's dates to an international format using this function:

```
def to_international_date(d):
    date = d.split("-")
​    day = date[0]
    month = date[1]
    year  = date[2]
​
   return '%s-%s-%s' % (year, month, date)
```

when i run this function, it shows me this error:

```
File "<ipython-input-22-02aa486b122c>", line 19
    ​ day = date[0]
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: You seem to have a non printing character where you should have spaces for the indent. Try deleting all the apparent white-space before `day` and then reindenting.

Comment: can you show that on code? thank's in advance

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how. Did my fix work for you?

Comment: I think there is a `U+200b` somewhere between two spaces in the indent.

Comment: it didn't work, maybe i just didn't understand the instructions, can you please clarify? what exactly should i delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other have suggested you have a `U+200B` character where there should be a space.  See this screenshot (I couldn't put this in the comments)...

[image]

Just delete where the two red dots are.